# Does adding x and y jitter to a seaborn linear plot change the fit values?

Tags: python, plot, regression, seaborn

I'm getting into seaborn for python and I have a quick question that I was not able to find an answer to. If I add jitter to a plot, does it actually change the fit values (such as r^2, p-value, etc) or is it just cosmetic for the plot's look?

Comparing for example `sns.lmplot("size", "tip", tips, x_jitter=.15)` from `sns.lmplot("size", "tip", tips)` at https://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/quantitative_linear_models.html

Comment: well, test it! plot the same data twice, with and without jitter, and look at the fit values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the regression is estimated on the original data; the jitter is applied to a copy of the data that is used to draw the scatterplot.

Comment: thanks a lot! :) may I ask how you know please? I could not find it in the documentation and would appreciate a pointer in case I missed it

Comment: Michael Waskom is the author of seaborn.